# Wordpress Plugin Update Using Bash and WP CLI Command

Tags: wordpress, bash

I am creating automatic plugin update function using bash and wp cli command.Using bash script i have checking update available plugins and storing those plugin names in a text file.
Now i want to update plugin one by one by reading the plugin name from text file i created. When reading plugin name from text file i want to display "Do you want to update  ?  Y/N " command on terminal. If user submit yes then update first plugin else show "Do you want to update  ?  Y/N " command for second plugin.

I have written code for that but its not working. Its not displaying "Do you want to update  ?  Y/N " on terminal. I added that code inside the **while** loop of bash script.

How can i display "Do you want to update  ?  Y/N " on terminal by using **while** loop in bash script ??? Then i want to update plugin based on user input is equal to Y. if user input is N then dont update that plugin.

Following are my code its not working now.

```
read -p "Do you want to list Plugin updates for $user ? Y/N " -n 1 -r
  echo
  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
  then
    echo
    # Display the list of plugins
    wp plugin list --update=available
    wp plugin list --update=available --field=name > plugins.txt
    while read p; do
    read -p "Do you want Plugin updates for $p ? Y/N " -n 1 -r
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
            then
            echo
            wp plugin update $p
        fi
        done <plugins.txt
  fi
  echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Finished!"
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP nor Wordpress. Remove these tags from it.

Comment: @adripanico thanks that was my mistake i removed that

Comment: @Inian How this will come under duplicate ?

Comment: See another duplicated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883363/read-input-in-bash-inside-a-while-loop

Comment: But those are different answer, I want to read file first then need to display that question on terminal based on answer need to update plugin

Comment: Both question are different question then how it will come under duplicate ??

Comment: Instead of seeking clarification here, you can spend time looking at the linked questions. Those have been provided for your understanding - look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688579/5291015 and modify your logic similarly

Comment: `while read -u 9 p; do
read -p "Do you want Plugin updates for $p ? Y/N " -n 1 -r
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
            then
            echo
            wp plugin update $p
        fi
        done 9<plugins.txt`

Comment: Add a seperate file descriptor `9` for the outer while read loop of your plugins.txt file, so that it does not affect your inner read command

Comment: while read -u 9 p; do read -p "Do you want Plugin updates for $p ? Y/N " -n 1 -r if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] then echo wp plugin update $p fi done 9<plugins.txt by using this one its skiping loop.For example first loop its working correct second loop its showing two Do you want Plugin updates for $p ? command